# Why is my text extending beyond its container when there is an image above it?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Why is my text extending beyond its container when there is an image above it?

http://www.blakearchive.org/blake/public/exhibits/test.html

The menuBarLine div and staticImage div and right column div (that's the column that contains the text, even though it's on the left) are set to table-cell, and the column div (their container) is set to table. When the image is not there, the right column behaves correctly. It does not extend beyond the viewport despite the menuBarLine on top of it, but when the image is there, it does.

Answer (score 0):

JQUERY

```
var rgheight = $(window).height() - ($('#staticImage').height() + $('#menuBarLine').height() + 40); $("#right").height(rgheight);
```

Change in css

```
#columns .right {
        position: relative;
        float: right;
        width: 34%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 2%;
        text-align: justify;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: table-cell;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px 
    }
```

NB: in rgheight th '+40' is used for padding calc: in the css rule i set padding top and bottom to 20px

For resize support the compelte js:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
      var rgheight = $(window).height() - ($('#staticImage').height() + $('#menuBarLine').height() + 40); $("#right").height(rgheight);
});
```

Then in your js change

```
function toggleMap() {
   var staticimgh = $('#staticImageSrc').height();
   if(staticimgh < 1) {$('#staticImageSrc').height(0)}  else {$('#staticImageSrc').css("height","auto");}    
}
```

Comment: I need it 100% because the height of the image above it changes with different galleries.

Comment: Notice that when you click Image Map, the image goes away and the column of text behave correctly. It doesn't extend beyond the viewport, despite its height being 100% and the menuBarLine above it. I need it to behave like this even with the image showing.

Comment: I repeat: yes, but I want to solve it so that I can keep the 100% height. It doesn't pose a problem without the image, even though the menuBarLine pushes it down a bit. The height of the image changes. I don't want to have to keep calculating it to calibrate things.

Comment: How about javascript?

Comment: How about it? What about it?

Comment: You can calc the height of this div with the formula (height of document(100%) - [image height + menuBarLine])

Comment: I tried this: <script>var height = $("#menuBarLine").height() + $("#staticImage").height();</script> <div id="right" class="right column" style="height: calc(100% - heightpx); box-sizing: border-box; display: block"></div> DIdn't seem to work.